# Numeration wrong in Amsart and Definition/Theorem environment not written bold

Tags: environments, enumerate, theorems, bold, amsart

When using the amsart documentclass I encounter the following numeration issue. When creating sections and subsections and writing definitions in them, the numeration of subsections and definitions/theorems interact with one another, e.g. when creating a theorem in subsection 1 and then creating a subsection after subsection 1, it says subsection 1.3 instead subsection 1.2. Furthermore the word "Definition" is written in a bold style, I would like to remove this to make it more plain, is that possible? I apologize if my code is bad, I am self taught in Latex. Thanks in advance for any help!

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newtheorem{defi}[subsection]{Definition}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{\thesection. }{0pt}{\centering}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\scshape}{\thesubsection. }{0pt}{\centering}[]

\title{A title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{defi} A definition
\end{defi}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How should definitions be numbered? Should it be totally independent of the section or subsection number? Or should the definitions be numbered within sections (so that the second definition of section 1 would be numbered 1.2)? Or within subsections?

Comment: @Vincent I would like to have the Definitions be numbered independently of the subsections but respecting the section they are in. Meaning that Definition 1.3 should be the third Definition or Theorem that appears in Section 1, Definition 2.5 being the fifth Definition/Theorem that appears in section 2 and so on. I think this is the most common way to numerate Definitions/Theorems? If not, I am also open to new ideas, but I usually dislike numbering a Definition/Theorem with 3 numbers, if its avoidable.

Comment: `\newtheorem{defi}[subsection]{Definition}` means that Defintions and subsections use the same counter, if you don't want that, delete the optional argument. It seems what you want is the default behaviour. or `\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]` if you want definitions numbered within sections

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. However when I do that, it only says Definition 1 Definition 2 etc. not respecting the section they are in. Furthermore, Theorems and Definitions don't respect each other, meaning Definition 1 followed by a Theorem will result in Theorem 1. I would like to have Definition 1.1 followed by Theorem 1.2 Theorem 1.3 Definition 1.4 and so on (if these are in section 1).

Comment: as I say use teh second optional argument if you want it numbered within sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheoremstyle{defis}%
    {3pt}% Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\scshape}% Head font
    {.}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}% Space after theorem head
    {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')
\theoremstyle{defis}
\newtheorem{defi}[thm]{Definition}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape}{\thesection. }{0pt}{\centering}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\scshape}{\thesubsection. }{0pt}{\centering}[]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{defi}
A definition
\end{defi}

\begin{thm}
A theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{defi}
Another definition
\end{defi}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\end{document}
```

##### About the numbering

`\newtheorem` has two optional arguments (that cannot be used at the same time) to control numbering. To summarize the idea, you can call `\newtheorem` as

```
\newtheorem{<env name>}{<text>}[<parent counter>]
```

or as

```
\newtheorem{<env name>}[<shared counter>]{<text>}
```

With the first option, the theorem-like environment `<env name>` will be numbered within the `<parent counter>`, like subsections are usually numbered within sections. With the second option, the environment `<env name>` will be numbered with the counter `<shared counter>`.

There are more details at page 5 of the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).

##### About the styles

Theorem-like environments come in different styles that can be switched before declaring a new environment with `\theoremstyle`. Three styles (`plain`, `definition` and `remark`) are provided by `amsthm`, but you can define others with `\newtheoremstyle`.

There are more details at page 9 of the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).

Comment: Thank you so much, it appears that this is exactly what I was looking for! One question though, it appears that when using what you wrote, all theorem environments automatically use the non-bold style despite not having [thm] in the argument. Why is that the case? The numbering still does not work, until I implement the [thm] argument. Thank you! Edit: Unfortunatley I can't upvote, since I don't have enough reputation, I am sorry.

Comment: @user243350 As I briefly explained in my answer, the styles are controlled with the `\theoremstyle` command. In my example, if you add more `\newtheorem`s after `\newtheorem{defi}...`, they will be in the style `defis` that I declared right before. To change the style, call again `\theoremstyle` after the definition of `defis`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation.